# Why is there moisture on some parts of my basement slab?

Tags: basement, moisture

In the mechanical room of a new construction house there is some moisture at the bottom pressure treated plated.  When I remove the vapor barrier and the insulation and check up against the  concrete wall there isn't any moisture on the wall itself or behind the wall.  It is only below the pressure treated plate and in front of it on this one wall.  I don't understand why this is and could really use some help with this.

One other concern i have is on one of the other interior walls that has the finished basement on the other side there is a little bit of moisture in one random spot as well which i don't understand. Right above this is the gas line for the furnace and when i touched the plug on the bottom side which is threaded on or whatever it is it felt a little wet but it isn't leaking not sure why there would be moisture on that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I want to make sure to take care of these moisture issues and don't want it to lead to something long term. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

The pipe could be cool and condensing humidity on the pipe (like a glass of ice water condenses moisture) . As for the moisture at the wall floor junction this is a common place for moisture to enter if there is standing water outside the foundation. We usually install a drain and gravel at the footings to prevent this and some times sumps (a pit that collects the water) with a pump to pump it out as the level rises. When I put bottom plates on concrete I use a sill seal (foam sheet to prevent the wood from sitting on the damp concrete. If this is new construction and your contract specified a dry basement you should be talking to the contractor. This is not an uncommon issue and there are measures to prevent the moisture from entering but usually excavation, draining and sealing are required. In some cases an internal sump is added to keep the water level below the slab.